# Assinging non-primitive values to user control properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I have built a user control that has a public property `string[] foo`.

Is it possible to assign this in the actual markup?

The type of project is ASP.NET webforms / web application.

Ive tried the following syntax, but it doesnt work: (It compiles but the value is never assigned).

```
<abc:MyControl runat="server" foo='<%# new string[]{"Hello"} %>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find [`PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.persistencemode.aspx) to be of interest.  The `PersistenceMode` attribute allows you to create properties with nested properties.  Note that in this case your aspx code will be using nested elements rather than properties, since elements can only store strings.

In that situation, you will be doing something like:

```
<abc:MyControl runat="server" >
    <foo>
        <element value="1" />
        <element value="2" />
    </foo>
</abc:MyControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

The databinding syntax is just a shorthand.

```
<abc:MyControl runat="server" ID="control1" foo='<%# new string[]{"Hello"} %>' />
```

is a shorthand for

```
<abc:MyControl runat="server" ID="control1" OnDatabinding="Databind_control1" />


protected void Databind_control1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((MyControl) sender).foo = new string[]{"Hello"};
}
```

Try it that way and see if it works.

Comment: Interesting. I havent checked, but I assume the DataBinding event is only called after the control implements a certain interface?

Comment: @maxp: all controls have a DataBinding event.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anything like that before, normally for arrays i do something like this:

```
<abc:MyControl runat="server" foo="This,Is,A,Test" />

public string foo {
    get;
    set;
}

public string[] foos {
    get { return foo.Split(','); }
    //set; if needed
}
```